# JSTL don't render vars

Tags: java, servlets, jstl, templating

When I use jstl tags `c:url` or something like that all work fine, but if I want print form parameter like that `${param.login}` jstl don't render it, and print `${param.login}`. How to fix that?

I use jstl from maven `javax.servlet > jstl > 1.2` and in document `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have web.xml by default generated from mvn simple web app.

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

I replace it on

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

</web-app>
```

And all works fine.